# casebox ECMS demo after installation

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, solr

After installation casebox ECMS demo gave following error:

```
 https://dev.casebox.org/audit

An error occured: exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message ''400' Status: Bad Request' in /var/www/html/casebox/httpsdocs/libx/Solr/Service.php:331 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/casebox/httpsdocs/libx/Solr/Service.php(1110): Apache_Solr_Service->_sendRawGet('`http://127.0.0....`') #1
/var/www/html/casebox/httpsdocs/classes/CB/Solr/Service.php(222): Apache_Solr_Service->search('', 0, 0, Array) #2 /var/www/html/casebox/httpsdocs/classes/CB/Search.php(418): CB\Solr\Service->search('', 0, 0, Array) #3
/var/www/html/casebox/httpsdocs/classes/CB/Search.php(37): CB\Search->executeQuery() #4 /var/www/html/casebox/httpsdocs/cores/audit/Demosrc/TreeNode/Offices.php(111): CB\Search->query(Array) #5
    /var/www/html/casebox/httpsdocs/cores/audit/Demosrc/TreeNode/Offices.php(51): Demosrc\TreeNode\Offices->getRootNodes() #6
    /var/www/html/casebox/httpsdocs/classes/CB/Browser.php(181): Demosrc\TreeNode\Offices->getChildren(Array, Array) #7
    /var/www/html/casebox/httpsdocs/classes/CB/Browser.php(98): CB\Browser->collectAllChildren() #8 
    /var/www/html/casebox/httpsdocs/classes/CB/BrowserView.php(19): CB\Browser->getChildren(Array) #9 [internal function]: CB\BrowserView->getChildren(Array) #10 /var/www/html/casebox/httpsdocs/remote/router.php(76): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #11 
    /var/www/html/casebox/httpsdocs/remote/router.php(123): ExtDirect\doRpc(Array) #12 {main}
```

please advice ..

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Solr log? Do you see the actual request at all?

Comment: i found this log file /opt/solr/logs/2014_12_17-072100381.start.log , but it is not ascii file , it is type is "PCX ver. 2.5 image data" , i get it by `file` command , and what i get through apache log was " Cant get solr log connection"